# XSLT different template based on child

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following source XML, which I have to transform in order to import into accounting software. In a nutshell, the resulting XML should have a static header and Multiple Lines (one Line per Project Ledger Line on the source XML). I would like to choose a different template for expenses and timesheets, because there are many differences in the accounting entries. One example is account code. The below example is very **simplified** only to differentiate account code, but there are a lot of other differences as well. The problem I have in my current transformation is that I only get one line, instead of 2, for some reason one is ignored. Please help,

thank you,

This is where you can access this project:
http://xsltransform.net/jyRYYjg/1

Source XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <TIMEATWORK xsl:version="1.0" server="localhost" database="TAW_TTC" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
        <PROJECT_LEDGER_LINE>
            <CalcVal11>600</CalcVal11>
            <Orig_Trans_Type>TIMESHEET</Orig_Trans_Type>
            <Project_Company_Accounts>
                  <Proj_AccName1>70600000</Proj_AccName1>
                  <Proj_AccName2>46141101</Proj_AccName2>
            </Project_Company_Accounts>
        </PROJECT_LEDGER_LINE>
        <PROJECT_LEDGER_LINE>
            <CalcVal11>50</CalcVal11>
            <Orig_Trans_Type>EXPENSE</Orig_Trans_Type>
            <Project_Company_Accounts>
                  <Proj_AccName1>70600000</Proj_AccName1>
                  <Proj_AccName2>46141101</Proj_AccName2>
            </Project_Company_Accounts>
        </PROJECT_LEDGER_LINE>
    </TIMEATWORK>
```

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
    xmlns:user="http://llpgroup.com/TAWnamespace"
    exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl user" >
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="TIMEATWORK">
    <SSC>
        <Header>
            <BudgetCode>A</BudgetCode>
        </Header>
        <Details>
            <Ledger>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="PROJECT_LEDGER_LINE">
                    <xsl:sort select="Orig_Trans_Type"/>
                </xsl:apply-templates>
            </Ledger>
        </Details>
    </SSC>

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="PROJECT_LEDGER_LINE">  
    <xsl:if test="Orig_Trans_Type = 'TIMESHEET'">
        <Line>
            <AccountCode><xsl:value-of select="Project_Company_Accounts/Proj_AccName1"/></AccountCode>
            <CurrencyCode><xsl:value-of select="CalcVal11"/></CurrencyCode>
            <DebitCredit>D</DebitCredit>
        </Line>
    </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="PROJECT_LEDGER_LINE">  
    <xsl:if test="Orig_Trans_Type = 'EXPENSE'">
        <Line>
            <AccountCode><xsl:value-of select="Project_Company_Accounts/Proj_AccName2"/></AccountCode>
            <CurrencyCode><xsl:value-of select="CalcVal11"/></CurrencyCode>
            <DebitCredit>D</DebitCredit>
        </Line>
    </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Desired Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SSC>
   <Header>
      <BudgetCode>A</BudgetCode>
   </Header>
   <Details>
      <Ledger>
           <Line>
            <AccountCode>70600000</AccountCode>
            <CurrencyCode>600</CurrencyCode>
            <DebitCredit>D</DebitCredit>
         </Line>
         <Line>
            <AccountCode>46141101</AccountCode>
            <CurrencyCode>50</CurrencyCode>
            <DebitCredit>D</DebitCredit>
         </Line>
      </Ledger>
   </Details>
</SSC>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have two (or more) templates matching the same node, only one of them will be applied.

If you want to have each template applied to a different type of the same node, use a *predicate* instead of `xsl:if`, e.g.:

```
<xsl:template match="PROJECT_LEDGER_LINE[Orig_Trans_Type = 'TIMESHEET']">  
    <Line>
        <AccountCode><xsl:value-of select="Project_Company_Accounts/Proj_AccName1"/></AccountCode>
        <CurrencyCode><xsl:value-of select="CalcVal11"/></CurrencyCode>
        <DebitCredit>D</DebitCredit>
    </Line>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="PROJECT_LEDGER_LINE[Orig_Trans_Type = 'EXPENSE']">  
    <Line>
        <AccountCode><xsl:value-of select="Project_Company_Accounts/Proj_AccName2"/></AccountCode>
        <CurrencyCode><xsl:value-of select="CalcVal11"/></CurrencyCode>
        <DebitCredit>D</DebitCredit>
    </Line>
</xsl:template>
```